# Yum install problem on netsolvps server

Tags: yum

I tried to install yum based on http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-install-yum-problems-installing-on-linux-redhat-fedora-commands-t471.html.

my current python is 2.4.6, red hot fedora core 6, 4.1.1-28, RPM 4.4.2.
 I tried with the yum 3.0.1 version for my current server configuration.
There is no configure file on 3.0.1 so i used make install command. All files complied without error.

If I run #rpm -q yum it says "package yum is not installed".

Whats the problem here on the yum installation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you install yum manually by compiling it manually, it won't be added to the rpm database. It will hence not be displayed in the `rpm -q` comand.

Comment: Whats the solution on installing yum on fedora core 6?

Comment: how will the yum added to rpm database?

Comment: Why would you want that? No need to, actually, because it isn't installed via rpm.

Comment: hi dadadom, I want to install yum for installing ffmpeg on fedora core 6. I followed the instruction but its not installed. Please tell me the answer clearly

Comment: How can i find that Yum installed properly? Do you follow my question?

Comment: It IS installed, should be in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`. It just isn't in the rpm database. Have you tried executing it?

Comment: hi dadadom,

I have not yet installed yum on my server.

mine is fedora core 6. if you know please tell me